# CPU usage of a blocking MPI_Recv in a thread

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mpi, cpu-usage

I have to write an MPI library where each process is doing some independent task but should react to some messages that can be sent unpredictably from other processes.
Both the sending and the receiving of these messages are part of the library and I cannot assume that library functions are going to be called often enough to follow the progress of an Immediate send or to check the receive queue. If the receiving process is doing some computation, the sending process may be blocked for some unpredictable amount of time.

The solution I'm currently interested in is to have each MPI process spawn a pthread thread pinned on its own CPU receiving these messages using a blocking receive in a loop. As I feared, my experiments show that this thread is taking half the CPU time (I hoped a blocking receive would somehow work with the kernel to avoid that).

I measure this behavior by having a fake computation function in one thread of a process, a blocking receive in another, and another process that sends a message to be received by the first process, but only when the computation is finished, this is enforced by a barrier after the computation and before sending a message. Only one thread of each process participate in the barrier so it works. This makes sure the receiving thread is really stuck waiting a message while the other is doing the computation. I then measure the compute time. The setup looks like this :

```
             +                 +
             | P0              | P1
          +--+--+              |
          |     |              |
compute() |     | Recv(1)      |
          |     |              |
          +--------------------+ Barrier
          |     |              |
          |     |              | Send(0)
          |     |              |
          +     +              +
```

I tried to change the blocking receive into an MPI_Iprobe loop that would yield the CPU to the other thread so that not too much CPU time is taken if there is no message to receive, for that I used the `sleep(0)` function acting as `pthread_yield` or `sched_yield` that require privilege to change the scheduling policy to a real time policy I'm not sure I need.
Then the `nanosleep` function to control the interval.

A simple version looks like this :

```
int flag;
while (1)
{
    MPI_Iprobe(1, 0, comm, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    if (flag == 1) break;
    sleep(0);
}

MPI_Recv(NULL, 0, MPI_INT, 1, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

This **seems** to solve my problem. In my experiments, the compute thread takes close to the same amount of time as if there was no other thread, compared to twice this time if I was just using a blocking receive `MPI_Recv` or if I did not use `sleep(0)`.

Here the code I use for measuring this :

```
#define COMPUTE_LOOP_ITER 200000000

void compute()
{
    int p[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < COMPUTE_LOOP_ITER; ++i)
    {
        p[i%2] = i;
    }
}

void * thread_recv_message(void * arg)
{
    MPI_Comm comm = *(MPI_Comm*) arg;

    int flag;
    while (1)
    {
        MPI_Iprobe(1, 0, comm, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        if (flag == 1) break;
        sleep(0);
    }

    MPI_Recv(NULL, 0, MPI_INT, 1, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    return NULL;
}

// Returns the compute() time on p0, 0 on others
double test(MPI_Comm comm)
{
    int s, p;
    double res = 0;
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &s);
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &p);

    if (p != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Requires 2 processes and no more in comm\n");
        fflush(stderr);

        MPI_Abort(comm, 1);
    }

    // Pin each process to its own core
    int cpuid = sched_getcpu();
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(cpuid, &cpuset);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

    if (s == 0)
    {
        pthread_t thr;
        pthread_attr_t attr;

        // Make sure the new thread is pinned on the same core
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

        pthread_create(&thr, &attr, thread_recv_message, &comm);

        double t1,t2;
        t1 = MPI_Wtime();

        compute();

        t2 = MPI_Wtime();

        MPI_Barrier(comm);

        res = t2 - t1;
        pthread_join(thr, NULL);
    }
    else // s == 1
    {
        MPI_Barrier(comm);
        MPI_Send(NULL, 0, MPI_INT, 0, 0, comm);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(comm);

    return res;
}
```

As I have little experience using MPI and none using it with threads, this solution seems quite fragile to me and I don't know if I can rely on it.

I'm using mpich 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 using Linux kernel version 4.4.0

This question is mostly asking for opinions or discussions regarding this problem and my current solution. I can explain more my testing method or provide more code if needed.

Comment: Something is very wrong if this kind of probe loop is faster than a blocking receive call. The probe loop does a lot more work.

Comment: What I measure is not the time to receive a message, but the time a computation is taking in a parallel thread on the same core while trying to receive a message. No message is actually received while doing the computation.

Comment: So then something is very, *very* wrong. The probe loop does a lot more work, constantly actively checking for a message that never arrives.

Comment: This is exactly why it takes twice more time for the computation in the other thread. It is approximately the same if I remove the probe loop before the blocking receive. What I compare is not the efficiency of having a probe loop before a receive or not. But trying to yield the CPU to the compute thread (here through sleep) when the probe loop realizes there is no message in the queue instead of trying right after.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no data dependency in the example between `compute` and `thread_recv_message`, it's hard to tell what exactly what's being done with the received data though.  I'm also not sure of the specific sense of "unpredictable" is being used in the sentence fragment "should react to some messages that can be sent unpredictably from other processes".

If you know for sure that rank *x* is going to be sending data to rank *y* at some point, then `MPI_Irecv` with `MPI_Test` would achieve that communication style without blocking the thread calling or completing the receive request.  You could interleave those `Irecv` and `Test` calls with your computations, or maybe call them once every 2 or 64 or 128 compute loop iterations, or whatever is suitable.

If the receiving rank doesn't know in advance which rank it's going to receive from, or the size of the data, then you would want to use `MPI_Probe` or `MPI_Iprobe` and use the returned `MPI_Status` struct.  Calls to `Iprobe` can be interleaved with your computation similarly to what I've described with `Irecv`.

It's also possible to use collectives like `MPI_Alltoall` or `MPI_Allgather` to serve a similar function as many ranks doing `Probes`, for example by exchanging an array containing byte counts that will be sent and received between pairs of ranks on subsequent point-to-point calls.  If you can guarantee that all ranks will eventually arrive at the collective call, this approach may make good use of implementation details only available to the MPI internals.  You can also use the equivalent non-blocking collectives (`Ialltoall`, `Iallgather`, etc.) to overlap this step with your computation.